# Resize image to its parent div on table

Tags: html, css, image

I was trying to make image table that fill window.

The following is my full source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ready</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      min-width: 2048px;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .player_buttons {
      table-layout: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .playerimg img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="player_buttons">
    <tr class="team" id="team_A">
      <td class="playerimg">
        <img src="../assets/profiles/1.jpg" />
      </td>
      <td class="playerimg">
        <img src="../assets/profiles/2.png" />
      </td>
      <td class="playerimg">
        <img src="../assets/profiles/3.jpg" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="team" id="team_B">
      <td class="playerimg">
        <img src="../assets/profiles/4.jpg" />
      </td>
      <td class="playerimg">
        <img src="../assets/profiles/5.jpg" />
      </td>
      <td class="playerimg">
        <img src="../assets/profiles/6.jpg" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

It is work when the images are small enough,
But in the case of image has big size, table (=.player_buttons) ignore its height (it over body and HTML's height).

I think image keep its aspect and min-size is problem.
How can I adjust images to their cell size?

Thanks.

ADD.

```
.playerimg img {height: 500px;}
```

-> it works (but I don't want to set height to 500px)

```
.playerimg img {height: 10%;}
```

-> ignore height.

Comment: why are you taking width of `body` as `2048px`?

Comment: sorry.
i have missed about that
i dont want to reduce width and my pictures will have 680px width. 
so i was set min-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html,body {
margin:0px;
}

.player_buttons {
table-layout:fixed;
height:100vh;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
}

.playerimg {
height:50vh;
}

.playerimg img {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Since you want to fit your images within your browser window, vh is a good option. This code isn't responsive but I hope it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you.
I have never known about 'vh'  (I`m not a web programmer or designer)
Image height width vh is working as good as px worked.
Your solution is working better than my previous tryings.
I`ll keep this solution as my plan B : )
But i still want plan A.

Answer (score 0):

What i would like to suggest you is that dont take `min-width` of body as `2048px` because it is spanning more area in some screens,instead you should use `min-width` as `100%` as will fit perfectly in every screen also take `max-width` and `max-height` attribute in your `img` tag,in that way height of your image will not overflow.Just paste the following code inside your `<style></style>` tag instead of your code.

```
html, body {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.player_buttons {
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width:  100%;
}
.playerimg img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

I hope it helps.Comment for further query

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
But, both of max-width and max-height was not working for my situation.(is ignored.) Image is still overflow from <tr> its parent.
Exactly, image is not overflow.
At i debug this with browser. table`s box model has overflowed height.

Using vh was working but it is not perfectly reponsive. so i will be searching other solution

Comment: you want all images to have same width and height irrespective of their original dimensions @YeomHyeonSeop

Comment: Exactly. yes.
and i want their`s height(2 rows)are fit to windows height